# Regex expression to match the First url after a space followed

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, url, pattern-matching

I want to match the First url followed by a space using regex expression  while typing in the input box.
For example :
if I type *www.google.com* it should be matched only after a space followed by the url 
ie `www.google.com<SPACE>`

### Code

```
$(".site").keyup(function()
{
   var site=$(this).val();
   var exp = /^http(s?):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
   var find = site.match(exp);

   var url = find? find[0] : null;

        if (url === null){
        var exp = /[-\w]+(\.[a-z]{2,})+(\S+)?(\/|\/[\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/])?/g;
        var find = site.match(exp);
        url = find? 'http://'+find[0] : null;
      }
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLL4E/1/)**

Please help, Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please please make a fiddle

Comment: @aelor Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kLL4E/1/

Comment: from the fiddle its not very clear about what you are trying to ask. A little more explanation can help me answer your question effectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a lookahead:

```
var exp = /[-\w]+(\.[a-z]{2,})+(\S+)?(\/|\/[\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/])?(?= )/g;
```

I only added this "(?= )" to your regex.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLL4E/4/)

Comment: Thank you, how to match the url on ending with space or &nbsp; please help

Comment: If you want to add space or &nbsp use: ((?= )|(?=\&nbsp)) See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kLL4E/5/

Answer (score 1):

you should be using a better regex to correctly match the query & fragment parts of your url. Have a look here ([What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)) for a correct IRI/URI structured Regex test.

But here's a rudimentary version:

```
var regex = /[-\w]+(\.[a-z]{2,})+(\/?)([^\s]+)/g;
var text = 'test google.com/?q=foo basdasd www.url.com/test?q=asdasd#cheese something else';
console.log(text.match(regex));
```

**Expected Result:**

```
["google.com/?q=foo", "www.url.com/test?q=asdasd#cheese"]
```

If you really want to check for URLs, make sure you include scheme, port, username & password checks just to be safe.

In the context of what you're trying to achieve, you should really put in some delay so that you don't impact browser performance. Regex tests can be expensive when you use complex rules especially so when running the same rule every time a new character is entered. Just think about what you're trying to achieve and whether or not there's a better solution to get there.